# Search database by shipping weight

Tags: magento-1.8, mysql

I have tried searching for this one but haven't had much luck. I have over 15k products in my Magento store. At some point we set some of the product's weight to 999. Now I need to generate a list of all of the products that have that set for the weight. I have been trying to find which table in the mysql database that has this information but I can't seem to find it.

In the end I am trying to make a SQL statement that gives me all the product ids for products whose weight is set to 999.

Thank you in advance to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code approach:

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(0);
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('weight', '999');
$ids = $collection->getAllIds();
//$ids is an array with what you are looking for
```

The SQL approach.

First get the `weight` attribute id.

```
SELECT 
    e.attribute_id 
FROM
    eav_attribute e 
LEFT JOIN 
    eav_entity_type et 
ON 
    e.entity_type_id = et.entity_type_id
WHERE 
    et.entity_type_code = 'catalog_product' AND
    e.attribute_code = 'weight'
```

Now get all the product ids with the weight `999`

```
SELECT 
    entity_id 
FROM 
    catalog_product_entity_decimal
WHERE
    attribute_id = {RESULT FROM PREV QUERY} AND
    value = 999
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you very much Marius!